# Conditional doesn't behave as expected

Tags: python

I'm an experienced programmer but new to Python. The attached code is my attempt at setting up a game board grid. I would like to fill the top part of the grid with 0s and the bottom part with 1s. However, this code always fills the entire board with 1s. I suspect I have made a beginner's error and just don't recognize it. The following is, I believe, a minimum reproducible example.

```
ROWS = 56 
COLS = 79

#put the cursor at position x,y on screen
def gotoxy(x,y):
    print ("%c[%d;%df" % (0x1B, y, x), end='')

# class for objects that populate the grid
class cell:
    Xloc = 0; Yloc = 0
    contents = 0

# 2-dim array of cells - here just for convenience
emptyBoard = [[cell for i in range(ROWS)] for k in range(COLS)]

# class for the board
class board:
    # cell field: Xloc & Yloc & contents of each cell
    cells = emptyBoard  

    # function: write the board to the screen
    def dispBoard(self):
        for x in range(0,COLS):
            for y in range(0, ROWS):
                gotoxy(x,y)
                print (str(self.cells[x][y].contents)) 

    # function: fill the cells with 0s or 1s 
    def fillBoard(self):
        for x in range(0,COLS):
           for y in range(0, ROWS):
                self.cells[x][y].Xloc = x
                self.cells[x][y].Yloc = y
                if y > 20:
                    self.cells[x][y].contents = 1
                else:
                    self.cells[x][y].contents = 0  

def main():    
    bord = board()
    bord.fillBoard()
    bord.dispBoard()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Off-topic: Your code will be more readable if you follow the [PEP 8 Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) — i.e. name your classes `Board` and `Cell`, and don't use camelCase variable or function names like `fillBoard` and `emptyBoard`.

Comment: Please [edit] to give your question a more descriptive title. Like, which conditional is not behaving as expected, `if y > 20`? What were you expecting, and what happened instead? For tips, see [ask].

Comment: Sidenote: `print(str(x))` is redundant of `print(x)` since `print()` converts its arguments to `str` automatically.

Comment: `gotoxy()` is overwriting my terminal. Please make something simpler without control codes

Answer (score 2):

When you're creating the `emptyBoard`, you're not creating a new object for each `cell` (see the missing parenthesis?)

```
emptyBoard = [[cell for i in range(ROWS)] for k in range(COLS)]
```

So all the `cell`s just refer to the base `cell` class, even if you change the content for one cell, it gets changed for all the `cell`s.

Now to fix this simply add the parenthesis and it will create a new object for each `cell` whose attributes will be independent from the other `cell`s.

```
emptyBoard = [[cell() for i in range(ROWS)] for k in range(COLS)]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks, problem solved. It WAS a beginner's error!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [kinshukdua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69599492/10426037) you are also missing the `__init__` method in your classes (you need it at least for the `cell` class).

```
class cell:
    def __init__(self):
       self.Xloc = 0
       self.Yloc = 0
       self.contents = 0
```

Otherwise `Xloc`, `Yloc` and `content` are class attributes, they are shared by all the instances of the class, hence no surprise all the element of the board have the same value.

And by the way, it would be better to move `emptyBoard = [[cell() for i in range(ROWS)] for k in range(COLS)]` in the `__init__` method of the `board` class if you want to have a more object oriented style. Something like this:

```
class board:
    def __init__(self):
        # cell field: Xloc & Yloc & contents of each cell
        sellf.cells = [[cell() for i in range(ROWS)] for k in range(COLS)]
```